# Passing light through airfold blades as a function of angle?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, angle

Consider an airfoil blade sunshade (see the diagram below). It consists of multiple flat rectangular shapes which are parallel to each other but make an angle ($v$) to the horizontal plane. The blades are separated by a distance ($s$) and have length ($L$). The blades are placed so that light rays parallel to the blades can fully pass, but light rays with an angle larger than ($w$), $w>v$, are fully blocked. Rays with angles between $v$ and $w$ will pass partly.

How can the passing light fraction be expressed as a function of the angle of the incident light?

[image]

Comment: Just so I'm understanding this correctly, is this a generalization of the single-slit experiment, which gives rise to a Fraunhofer diffraction pattern? Also, shouldn't the angles where the light passes partly be between the drection parallel to blades and $v$, not between $v$ and $w$?

Comment: I don't think this is as complicated as Fraunhofer, there's no diffraction involved, its a geometric problem to determine the proportion of shadow over lighted area the shade makes as the angle of the light source changes.  I might come back to this when I've had some coffee.....

Comment: I'm sure there is no diffraction involved since the purpose is to block/let through thermal radiation which has wavelengths in nano meters. These blades could be about 10 cm so they are not in the same order of magnitude. It is simply an issue where I can't figure out the projection on a vertical wall behind the blades.

Comment: Okay. I wasn't sure if we were talking about blades that were a great deal of distance apart (relative to the wavelengths of the expected radiation) or if there were going to be diffraction effects present that we would need to account for. I've got ideas, but I need to finish mowing the lawn.

Comment: Are you assuming that the fraction is the ratio between the "shade" length and S?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is much simpler to conceptualize if we align our coordinate system so that the light rays are parallel to a coordinate axis:
[image: Louvres]

Left: $\varphi \lt \beta$. Right: $\varphi \gt \beta$.

Above, $S$ is the distance between the pivot points, $L$ is the width of the [louvres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louvre_%28window%29), $\beta$ is the solar elevation angle (the angle between horizontal and the light rays), and $\varphi$ is the angle between the louvres and horizontal.

Since the wall is vertical, $0 \le \beta \lt 90°$. We exclude negative angles based on the sun then being under the horizon. We exclude angles above $90°$ because they are directly above or behind the wall (shaded by the roof or the other side of the wall).

Let's make these really adjustable louvres, with $-90° \lt \varphi \lt 90°$. Thus,
$$-90° \le \beta - \varphi \le 180°$$

As stated in the question, when $\beta = \varphi$ all light passes, so the louvres have no appreciable thickness. We also assume the louvres cover the entire wall we care about.

Perpendicular to the light, $d$ is the distance between louvres, and $h$ is the part shadowed by each louvre. The fraction of light passed through the louvres is therefore
$$\alpha = \left \lbrace \begin{matrix}
1 - \frac{h}{d}, & h \lt d \\
0, & h \ge d
\end{matrix} \right.$$
Note that even though the wall is not vertical, the ratio of shadow per louvre, $h/d$, is still valid. The angle between the wall and the light just scales both $h$ and $d$ (by $1/cos(\beta)$), that's all.

Using the properties of the two right triangles, we have
$$h = L \sin(\lvert\beta-\varphi\rvert)$$
and
$$d = S \cos\beta$$
Therefore the fraction of light passing through the louvres is
$$\alpha = \max\left( 0, \; 1 - \frac{L}{S} \frac{\sin \lvert\beta-\varphi\rvert}{\cos\beta} \right )$$

Even if the angle between the louvres and light was obtuse, the above still holds. In the illustration above, at $(\beta-\varphi) \gt 90°$ the louvres hang down left; at $0° \lt (\beta-\varphi) \lt 90°$ they hang down right, and when $-90° \lt (\beta-\varphi) \lt 0°$, they hang up right.

Comment: Nice picture to see light incidence situation.